# Algolia Search tagging based on Rails associations, how to update tags when association is created/destroyed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algolia

I have a simple algolia setup with a few models and each model has a few attributes, ex:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AlgoliaSearch

  algoliasearch do
    attributes :id, :name

    add_attribute :_tags    
  end

  def _tags
    users = []

    self.connections.each do |connection|
      users.push('user_' + connection.user_id.to_s)      
    end

    users
  end
end
```

The setup above easily allows me to restrict search results on a per user basis so that the user only sees the records that they have permission to see if they are associated/related in the Rails app.

However, when the `Connection` model is created or destroyed, the `User` model is unaware and thus affects the search results negatively.

How can I add an ActiveRecord callback to the `Connection` model and update the `_tags` key on the record accordingly so that the `_tags` is updated to include or exclude (based on create or destroy)?

tldr: `_tags` on a record in Algolia has the value `['user_1', 'user_2']` determined by associations in Rails.  The association between the record in Algolia and `user_2` is removed from the DB in Rails, how can I remove `user_2` from the array of tags on the record in Algolia?

Comment: Is the algolia search executed in the browser or from your server?

Comment: In the browser but it's irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [pending issue](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails/issues/74) on GitHub about that: detecting changes in the underlying associations.

In the meantime, you could force the indexing of the `User` object in an after_save callback of the `Connection` object:

```
class User
  algoliasearch do 
  # [...]
  end
end


class Connection
  after_save :reindex_user
  belongs_to :user

  private
  def reindex_user
   self.user.reindex!
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you give an example in code?  Don't understand "force the indexing."  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just edited it fixing the class name + added code sample.